# Why is my xml parse storing the same result multiple times in my python dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse the xml result returned when the user enters a criteria in python, in order request data from an external api. It does work but the thing is, it is returning/printing the same result multiple times. Please help!

```
anime= []
anime_details= []
title= []
pic= []
plot = []
    
#loop used to iterate over each tag under anime
for tag in anime_info.findall('anime/info'):

    #expression used to store tag discriptions 
    value = tag.attrib['type']

    #bool used to check any tag that contained a picture
    if value == 'Picture':
        #expression used to store the url for the image of the anime
        pic = tag.attrib['src']
        # anime_details.append(pic)

    #bool used to check any tag that contained the title of the anime
    if value == 'Main title':
        #expression used to print the data that is within the tag eg:name of anime
        title = tag.text
        # anime_details.append(title)
    
    #bool used to check any tag that contained the plot 
    if value == "Plot Summary":
        #expression used to print the data that is within the tag eg:summerization of plot
        plot = tag.text
    
    #expression used to add anime details to the anime_details dictionary
    anime_details.append({'title': title, 'picture': pic, 'plot': plot})

# anime.append(anime_details)
for anime_details in anime_details:
    print(anime_details['title'])
    print(anime_details['picture'])
    print(anime_details['plot'])
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOBRF.png)

[XML Snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZrpw.png)

Comment: Did you check that the xml does not contains multiple time the same anime. (Remake, different season, … )

Comment: @PtitXav I used the main title which is only indicated once in the xml results. I updated my question to include a snapshot of the output. For some reason once it locates a new title it duplicates it multiple times before moving on to the next.

Comment: Please share an excerpt of the xml

Comment: @Tranbi sorry for the late reply. I have attached  snip called "XML Snip".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You loop in xml file on anime/info instead of looping on anime and then searching for info in anime. This means that you get one anime_details per info, so multiple anime_details for each anime :

```
…
animes_details = []

# loop on anime nodes
for anime_node in anime_info.findall("anime"):

    # set default valued
    title = "?"
    pic = ""
    plot = ""

    # loop on info of anime node
    for tag in anime_node.findall('info'):

        #expression used to store tag discriptions 
        value = tag.attrib['type']
        …

    #expression used to add anime details to the anime_details dictionary
    animes_details.append({'title': title, 'picture': pic, 'plot': plot})

for anime_details in animes_details:
    print(anime_details['title'])
    print(anime_details['picture'])
    print(anime_details['plot'])
```

Edit : as spotted by @Drey , default must be set out of inner loop.

Comment: It worked!! I never even thought about reconstructing my loop like how you suggested. There was one edit I had to make, which was to set my defaults outside of the nested loop and it worked like a charm. Thank you so much for coming back to my question.

Comment: You are right about resetting the defaults : should be outside the inner loop

Answer (score 0):

In your code the index loop is the array :

```
for anime_details in anime_details:
```

Comment: I made a change there but still having challenges. Thank you for answering.